# Get the missing dates substituted with 0 in one column and showing a varchar value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, left-join

I have 3 columns in TableData, namely CDate, Drivername, Trips. Now I am creating a monthly report in order to show the list of drivers with their trips. Also I want to show the driver's data (showing trips=0) who did not work on a specific day(s) during this month.
I have tried "join" methods, `coalesce` function but all in vain... I appreciate if anyone here could help me fix this issue.

I have seen so many sample queries here which yields one column result that sets the value to zero or getting the aggregate of single column.

[image: TableData contains the actual data]

[image: TableCalc the table that contains Dates]

[image: TableOutput is what am looking for]

I actually need for the complete month; but for easier reference i have used the date till 8th of May 2022. Please note, there are around 45 drivers in the list..
Below are some workarounds from me:

```sql
select CDATE,DriverName from(
select CDate=convert(date,CDate) from TableCal where month(CDate)=5 AND year(CDate)=2022
)AllDays left join
(select TDate,Drivername,Trips=count(*) from TableData where month(TDate)=5 and year(TDate)=2022 group by drivername,TDate
)tm on CDate=TDate group by Cdate,DriverName
 ORDER BY Drivername,Cdate
```

[image: Wrong Output]

Sample DDL and DML as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableData](
    [CDate] [date] NULL,
    [DriverName] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Trips] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO tableData(CDate,DriverName,Trips)     VALUES('2022-05-01','Michael',5)  
INSERT INTO tableData(CDate,DriverName,Trips)     VALUES('2022-05-03','Michael',7)  
INSERT INTO tableData(CDate,DriverName,Trips)     VALUES('2022-05-04','Michael',8)  
INSERT INTO tableData(CDate,DriverName,Trips)     VALUES('2022-05-05','Michael',13) 

INSERT INTO tableData(CDate,DriverName,Trips)     VALUES('2022-05-01','Sam',5)  
INSERT INTO tableData(CDate,DriverName,Trips)     VALUES('2022-05-04','Sam',5)  
INSERT INTO tableData(CDate,DriverName,Trips)     VALUES('2022-05-05','Sam',13)  
INSERT INTO tableData(CDate,DriverName,Trips)     VALUES('2022-05-06','Sam',9)  


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableCal](
    [CDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO TableCal(CDate)     VALUES('2022-05-01')
INSERT INTO TableCal(CDate)     VALUES('2022-05-02')  
INSERT INTO TableCal(CDate)     VALUES('2022-05-03')  
INSERT INTO TableCal(CDate)     VALUES('2022-05-04')  
INSERT INTO TableCal(CDate)     VALUES('2022-05-05')  
INSERT INTO TableCal(CDate)     VALUES('2022-05-06')  
INSERT INTO TableCal(CDate)     VALUES('2022-05-07')  
INSERT INTO TableCal(CDate)     VALUES('2022-05-08')
```

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realized you had a "date table". However, I now see that TableCal actually has one record per month. That is not enough. The table needs to have every day in it, and that should be left joined to the original data.

Comment: What does TableCal represent? I thought it was a date table, but now I am not sure. In the beginning of your question, it has one record per month. Then later, it is one record per day for 5/1 through 5/8. Then in your workaround query, it seems to be one record per month again.

Comment: If some of those images are redundant please remove them & for the others please use text to make them redundant & remove them. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] Please make data representative but minimal. What does your "workaround" code have to do with your question? What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your sweet approach... I highly appreciate your time you spent in answering my query...

Indeed, @nbk's solution was the perfect one that I was looking for.... Thanks again to all... Have a nice coding day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a CTE you don't need a calender table, you can still used it, if  you have dates to exclude for example

But you should know that Sql SERVER 2012 has reached its end of Life last July(2022) see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-sql-server-2012

So you should think about migrating

```
with cte as (
    select 
        DriverName, 
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, min(CDate)), 0)  dt
        , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, min(CDate)), -1) maxDt 
        from tableData
        WHERE month(CDate)=5 AND year(CDate)=2022 
        group by DriverName
    union all
    select 
        DriverName,  
        dateadd(DAY, 1, dt),
        maxDt
    from cte
    where dt < maxDt
)
select c.DriverName,  FORMAT (c.dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), coalesce(t.Trips, 0) avalue 
from cte c
left join tableData t 
    on  t.DriverName = c.DriverName
    and t.CDate = c.dt  
order by c.DriverName,  c.dt
```

| DriverName | (No column name) | avalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | 2022-05-01 | 5 |
| Michael | 2022-05-02 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-03 | 7 |
| Michael | 2022-05-04 | 8 |
| Michael | 2022-05-05 | 13 |
| Michael | 2022-05-06 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-07 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-08 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-09 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-10 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-11 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-12 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-13 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-14 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-15 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-16 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-17 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-18 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-19 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-20 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-21 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-22 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-23 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-24 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-25 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-26 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-27 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-28 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-29 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-30 | 0 |
| Michael | 2022-05-31 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-01 | 5 |
| Sam | 2022-05-02 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-03 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-04 | 5 |
| Sam | 2022-05-05 | 13 |
| Sam | 2022-05-06 | 9 |
| Sam | 2022-05-07 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-08 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-09 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-10 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-11 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-12 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-13 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-14 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-15 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-16 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-17 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-18 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-19 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-20 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-21 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-22 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-23 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-24 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-25 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-26 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-27 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-28 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-29 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-30 | 0 |
| Sam | 2022-05-31 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xhjLjl31)

Comment: Dear @nbk,  Thank you so much for your query... Indeed it worked like a charm.... I really appreciate your instant response...